# What does SOFT_INPUT_MODE_CHANGED do?

Tags: android

I can't seem to find any good reference on the usage of `WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_MODE_CHANGED`. Even the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#SOFT_INPUT_MODE_CHANGED) does not include any description of the constant. What is it? What does it do?

The reason I asked is that in the source code that I have, it has these lines of code:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_MODE_CHANGED);
}
```

and affects the behavior (panning / resizing) of my activity when showing the soft keyboard.